# UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods Not Called When Delegate Not UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a view that contains several images, each intended to be selected from the device's photo library.

I followed an example from [the Food Tracker tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/), using Tap Gesture Recognizers, one for each image view.

I've wired an outlet for each UIImageView into my view controller.

When an image is selected, I want the image from the device's photo library to be set to the image property of the selected UIImageView. The way I thought to do this is to use closures encapsulated into a class adopting the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol. However, the methods on this class are never called. If I instead make my view controller the delegate, the methods are correctly called (but I don't know which image to set).

Here's some code to clarify:

```
// Encapsulate callbacks for the selected image
class ImagePicker: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var select: (image: UIImage) -> Void
    var cancel: () -> Void

    init(select: (image: UIImage) -> Void, cancel: () -> Void) {
        self.select = select
        self.cancel = cancel
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        cancel()
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        select(selectedImage)
    }
}
```

Then within my view controller, I have wired this method to the gesture recognizer:

```
@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    let imagePicker = ImagePicker(
        select: {(image: UIImage) -> Void in
            let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
            imageView.image = image
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        },
        cancel: {() -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    )
    imagePickerController.delegate = imagePicker
    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The methods are never called. I've set break points (and printed to the console) in both the closures and in the two delegate methods (`imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_:)` and `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)`).

Is there something else I need to implement? Or is this just "the wrong way to do it"? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your `ImagePicker` goes out of scope at the end of the `selectImageFromPhotoLibrary` function. Therefore the image picker's delegate is gone. You need to keep a strong reference to the `ImagePicker`.

Comment: Thanks, rmaddy. You're correct. Just moving the variable to an instance variable allowed the methods to be called. Now I need to figure out why calling the method is not working. I obviously need to read further about Swift memory management. And why there was no error reported.

If you convert your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Something else I was doing wrong was the call to select. It should be `select(image: selectedImage)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ImagePicker` instance goes out of scope at the end of the `selectImageFromPhotoLibrary` function. Therefore the image picker's delegate is gone. You need to keep a strong reference to the `ImagePicker`. Using an instance variable is a likely option.